# Problems setting up dokka in Maven

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, kotlin-dokka

I have added the following to my pom.xml, based on this page:

https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka#using-the-maven-plugin

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.dokka</groupId>
    <artifactId>dokka-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.19-dev-15</version>
</dependency>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>jcenter</id>
        <name>JCenter</name>
        <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.dokka</groupId>
    <artifactId>dokka-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.19-dev-15</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>pre-site</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>dokka</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <dokkaPlugins>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.dokka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-as-java-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.19-dev-15</version>
            </plugin>
        </dokkaPlugins>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I run the project, I get the following errors:

> Dependency 'org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-maven-plugin:0.9.19-dev-15' not found

> Plugin 'org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-maven-plugin:0.9.19-dev-15' not found

Can someone help out with this configuration? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For this version add the Kotlin Dev Maven repository to you project:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>k-dev</id>
            <name>K-dev</name>
            <url>https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev/</url>
        </repository>
</repositories>
```

You can see the URL of the repository for this library page on the [Maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.dokka/dokka-maven-plugin/0.9.19-dev-15):

> **Note:** this artifact is located at Kotlin Dev repository (https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev/)